# jackson.databind.JsonNode has() returning true on null fields(when it shouldn't)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jsonnode

when iterate through a List of JSONNODES like so

```
 for(JsonNode result: results){
   if (predicate==Predicate.GREATER_THAN && result.has("JarVersion")){
        //gets in here even though 'JarVersion' is null
        if(result.get("JarVersion").textValue().compareTo(version) > 0)
          //fails here because nulls pass through
```

for some reason even though result.get("JarVersion") returns null, it passes the result.has() check.

Is there an issue with the has() function of this library?

I looked into it and on the interface all it is doing is `results.get(fieldName) != null`, yet there are many null cases that get through (and break) my code

Comment: I think you want to use `asText()` instead of `textValue()`. `"for non-String values (ones for which isTextual() returns false) null will be returned."` - this is from javadoc at `textValue()` method.

Comment: I think I found the issue. In the documentation...

```NOTE: this method will return <code>true</code> for explicitly added
     * null values
```

Comment: @KunLun nice catch! Thanks

Comment: I say that because I think `result.has("JarVersion")` is `true`, but `textValue()` can't convert value to `String`. P.S.: so i was right?

Comment: @KunLun nope, I thought it would, but still doesn't work. I check like this
```!result.get("JarVersion").asText("").equals("")``` and this ```result.get("JarVersion") != null```, but I still get empty strings coming through

Comment: Can you give us some sample of json?

Comment: you know what, I a different issue that I assumed led to this one, I apoglogize, it was an issue on my front end. The two checks we found do make it work (where it wasn't before).